# Splitting combined string for checklistbox control

Tags: c#, split, checklistbox

**RE: Customised Web Application for Microsoft CRM Online**

I've programmed a checklistbox control in ASP.NET (C#) Web Form that displays a number of items from Microsoft CRM Online via LINQ.

```
List<string> selDropdown = chkMyItemsHere.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(li => li.Selected)
                .Select(li => li.Value)
                .ToList();

string ListBoxValues = string.Join(", ", selDropdown);
```

This works perfectly and I'm able to save the string into one field (i.e. 'string value, string value').

Now, on Page_Load I need to split the values from the combined string and tick the relevant checkboxes in the checkListbox.

```
string[] k = i.LINQFIELD.Split(',');
for (int m = 0; m <= k.Length - 1; m++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= chkMyItemsHere.Items.Count; x++)
    {
       if (chkMyItemsHere.Items[x].Value == k[m])
       {
          chkMyItemsHere.Items[x].Selected = true;
       }
     }
}
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be re-populating my checkboxlist? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've followed a number of articles on the internet and cannot seem to workout why I can't take the value store of 'dog, cat' and then select the corresponding checkboxes in the Checklistbox.

Comment: You are trying to compare "cat" (3 characters) to " cat" (4 characters). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In your code that works, you have this:

```
string.Join(", ", selDropdown);
```

In your code that does not, you have this:

```
string[] k = i.LINQFIELD.Split(',');
```

### Do you see it?

As a solution, I propose you declare a constant variable like so:

```
private const string SPLIT_VARIABLE = ", ";
```

Now you have this:

```
string.Join(SPLIT_VARIABLE, selDropdown);
```

and

```
string[] k = i.LINQFIELD.Split(SPLIT_VARIABLE);
```

Comment: Ahhhh - I can see that I have the space at the end of the Join now... but using your example so that I can have ', ' so there is a gap in the DB doesn't work as the const isn't allowed to be set as that (well, so Visual Studio tells me).  

The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Comment: Some compilers have multiple overloads for the `Split` function. It depends what version of Visual Studio you are using. If yours does not have that overload, use `SPLIT_VARIABLE.ToArray()`.

Comment: You could also add `chkMyItemsHere.Items[x].Value.Trim() == k[m].Trim()` to your code, and it would work.

Comment: @Chris, did my answer solve your problem? No upvote or accepted answer, so is something still missing?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing how you split your comma-delimited string -- as suggested by jp2code to make sure there aren't extraneous spaces in each array element -- you can also use LINQ to select the items in your checkboxlist based on what's in your "k" string array:

```
(from i in chkMyItemsHere.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
             where Array.Exists<string>(k, s => { return i.Value == s; })
             select i).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Selected = true);
```

This way, you don't have to use a nested for loop to select your list items.